# Set collation order in shell sort to not ignore special characters

Tags: sorting, postgresql

I am looking for a solution for sorting in postgres but it seems to be more of a problem of collation and therefore I ask the question for the standard Unix sort command instead.

I have the following data:

```
A_A1
A\A2
A_A2
A\A1
```

after sort I get:

```
cat test.txt |sort

A_A1
A\A1
A_A2
A\A2
```

but I want:

```
A_A1
A_A2
A\A1
A\A2
```

I also tried `LANG=C cat...` but to no avail.
So which collation rule would allow me to not ignore the special characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man sort`:

```
Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.
```

So:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort test.txt
A\A1
A\A2
A_A1
A_A2
```

so the C locale does sort after byte value.

---

You need to do

```
$ cat test.txt | LC_ALL=C sort
```

if you want to pipe it like that (but always try to use the file name version directly if it's available).

---

The primary environment variable affecting this is `LC_COLLATE`. If `LC_ALL` is set though, it trumps all specific `LC_` values. If neither `LC_ALL` nor `LC_COLLATE` are set, it falls back on `LANG`. If *that* is not set, it defaults to locale `C`.

Comment: Arrgh stupid me.

`LANG=C` works but not as

    `LANG=C cat test.txt|sort`

but only 

    `cat test.txt|LANG=C sort`

of course!

Comment: @Fabian: `LANG=C` does not work for me, actually, but that depends on that I have LC_COLLATE (which is the primary environment variable that affects collation). I'll add info on this in my answer.